# how can I correctly retrieve icons for a weather application from openweathermap?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<article>
        <br/><br/>

    <div class = "resultats">

            <label> Weather : </label>
            <img src ="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{weather.icon}}.png">

            <p> {{ weather.weather[0].description }}</p> 
            <p>Wind speed (meter/sec): {{ weather.wind.speed }}</p>
            <span class="temperature">Temperature (Fahrenheit): {{ ((weather.main.temp) -273.15)*1.8+32 }} </span>
            <br/>
            <span class="temperatureCelsius">Temperature (Celsius): {{ ((weather.main.temp) -273.15) }} </span>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
</article>
```

This code takes all the information but I don't have an icon result. I think it's the URL link which is not write correctly.

Comment: What's the `{{weather.icon}}`? Are you using Angular or any framework like that?

Comment: I use angular 6

Comment: Try to log `weather.icon` and share it with us please

Comment: probably a redundant ".png" extension if i had to guess

Comment: https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions    I need to retrieve the icon from this URL, but when I execute my code I have am URL error 404, It is an URL error, and I tried to write it differently but without success

Answer (score 0):

In your component file, declare the icon source string with interpolation:

```
iconSrc: string  = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${weather.icon}.png`;
```

Then use the binding in your template:

```
<img [src]="iconSrc" />
```

Also you have an extra space after your src attribute in your image tag and removing that would also solve it.

Comment: https://github.com/shirleytruffierblanc/App-Weather-Last-Version.git  you can see my project on github in order to understand better my problem if you need it

Comment: here you go `<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{weather.weather[0].icon}}.png">`